# Name a list with Table

Tags: list-manipulation, variable

I am struggling to find a way to assign a value from a list to names from another pre-defined list with Table[].

```
names = {first, second, third}
```

```
numbers = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
```

What I want is:

```
first = {1, 1}
second = {2, 2}
third = {3, 3}
```

so that {1, 1} is stored in *first* etc.

I tried the following:

```
namelists = Table[(names[[i]]) = (numbers[[i]]), {i, Length[names]}];
```

In this case, namelists[[1]] = {1, 1}, however *first* does not store any information...

Comment: If you are not *set* on using `Table` then `MapThread[Set, {names, numbers}]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Clear[first, second, third]
names = {first, second, third}
numbers = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
Table[Evaluate[names[[i]]] = numbers[[i]], {i, 3}]
first
second
third
```

Comment: Since you can make multiple assignments at the same time, you don't need the `Table`: the "vectorized" `Evaluate@names = numbers` will work too.

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear[first, second, third]    

names = {first, second, third};
numbers = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};

With[{names = names}, names = numbers];

first
```

> {1, 1}

Answer (score 8):

With the following definitions:

```
Clear[first, second, third]
names = {first, second, third}
numbers = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
```

a one-liner approach would be:

```
Evaluate@names = numbers
```

You can see how this works using Trace:

```
Clear[first, second, third]
names = {first, second, third}
numbers = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
Trace[Evaluate@names = numbers]

(* Out: 
{{names, {first, second, third}}, 
   {numbers, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}}, 
   {first, second, third} = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, 
   {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

`MapThread` works well for this task.

```
numbers = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
Clear[first, second, third]
names = {first, second, third};
MapThread[Set, {names, numbers}]; 
{first, second, third}
```

> `{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}`